# Most efficient way to concatenate multiple strings in C++

Tags: c++, string, string-concatenation

I want to find the most efficient way to concatenate multiple strings of type `std::string`.

One of the issues is that I also have a char within it, and another issue is that I need it to be as fast as possible.
Let's say I have the following variables defined:

```
std::string defaultName = "default"; 
std::string paramFullName = "Elasticity";
```

### First try:

```
std::string paramName = defaultName + "_" + paramFullName[0] + "_";
```

This code does not compile with Intel C++14 compiler.

### Second try:

```
std:string paramName;
paramName += defaultName + "_";
paramName += paramFullName[0];
paramName += "_";
```

This time the output came as expected:

> "default_E_"

I still wanted to test another way:

### Third try:

```
std:string paramName;
paramName.append(defaultName + "_");
paramName.append(1, paramFullName[0]);
paramName.append("_");
```

Output was OK again, because of the separation of the `char` from the `string`s.

> "default_E_"

When testing for timing, I've found out that the `append` option is faster that the `+=`.

I want to know if there is a better, more efficient way, 
and also could I minimize the number of lines so it wouldn't look so ugly?

Comment: First way works fine. Did you rememeber to `#include <string>` and also spell `defaulName` correctly and/or remember the `;` at the end of `std::string paramFullName = "Elasticity"`?

Comment: I would create a result string with the required length and write into it to avoid unnecessary memory allocations. `append` and other concatenation methods could require more memory and allocate new memory in each step.

Comment: `defaulName + "_" + paramFullName[0] + "_"` should be parsed as `((defaulName + "_") + paramFullName[0]) + "_"`. I.e. all "additions" should be between either a `std::string` and a `const char*`, or between a `std::string` and a `char`, which both should work fine.

Comment: Also, when asking questions about code that fails to build, *please* include the actual errors you get. And preferably a [mre] of the code that fails to build.

Comment: On a different (and unrelated) note, why do you use string literals for single characters? Instead of e.g. `"_"` why not use `'_'`?

Comment: Something like this: https://wandbox.org/permlink/OCJjiFczgCD3MRq3 You can probably improve it using `memcpy`.

Comment: std::stringstream

Comment: Here is a version with `memcpy`: https://wandbox.org/permlink/5YihdNbrjTGtUK2U

Comment: @BuildSucceeded It's long since I did last performance comparisons, but the last time `std::stringstream` was much slower than anything else.

Comment: to be fast I would avoid strings everywhere but for I/O and use enums or other simpler datastructures. Once you do I/O you can still convert encoded information to `std::string`, and as I/O is inherently slow, its not that important to have the fastest string concatenation then

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, thank you for your comments. I did supply minimal reproducible codes in my question, each code piece is easily copied and reproduced. Second, I used string literals so it will be easier for me to add the to the string, since I saw that adding `char` gave me a problem, each `char` I wanted to add, I needed to write in a different line, not in concatenation with `string`

Comment: @jabaa, in order to know in advance the length of the string I will need to sum up all sizes of the strings I want to add. The above was just an example, and I guess it might be faster, but wouldn't it take longer to find `size()` of all strings?

Comment: What compiler are you really using? The Intel `icc` compiler? Which version of it? What flags and options do you pass to the compiler when building? Because the first attempt you made [works fine in all the big three, as well as the 2021.5.0 version of Intel's ICC](https://godbolt.org/z/Kxjoh1Ghb).

Comment: @jabaa, can you give an example how to write into a `string` multiple strings after I create it with fixed size allocated?

Comment: Consider https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is most likely going to involve allocating a destination string once, which means you will need to know the size of all your input strings. Luckily `std::string`, string literals and individual characters have a O(1) size, so only c style strings need to be looped twice.

```
namespace string_builder
{
    std::size_t length(char str)
    {
        return 1;
    };
    
    void append(std::string & dest, char str)
    {
        dest.push_back(str);
    }
    
    std::size_t length(const char * str)
    {
        return std::strlen(str);
    };
    
    void append(std::string & dest, const char * str)
    {
        dest.append(str);
    }
    
    template<std::size_t N>
    std::size_t length(const char (&str)[N])
    {
        return N;
    }
    
    template<std::size_t N>
    void append(std::string & dest, const char (&str)[N])
    {
        dest.append(str, N);
    }
    
    std::size_t length(const std::string & str)
    {
        return str.size();
    }
    
    void append(std::string & dest, const std::string & str)
    {
        dest.append(str);
    }
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::string concat(const Ts &... ts)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve((string_builder::length(ts) + ...));
    (string_builder::append(result, ts), ...);
    return result;
}
```

[See it on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b5b1048d9c4b669b)

Answer (score -2):

Use the "built-in" C++ "stringbuilder" :

```
#include <iostream> // for std::cout
#include <sstream>  // for std::ostringstream
#include <string>   // for std::string

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::string s("Two");
    oss << "One" << ' ' << s << ' ' << "Three";
    std::string result(oss.str()); // concat result
    std::cout << result; // Console Output: One Two Three
}
```

OR (more concise, not using result variable)

```
std::cout << oss.str();
```

Using ostringstream object you can also concatenate any type of variables, provided that all of them are "streamable" (standard stream or the type itself know how to serialize what you are sending after operator << ):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
int one = 1;
std::string s("Two");
oss << one << ' ' << s << ' ' << 3;
std::string result(oss.str()); // concat result
std::cout << result; // Output: 1 Two 3
```

Comment: I downvoted because the question asks for most efficient, and according to my experience stringstreams are slower than all other options.